# Can't disable email alerts

Tags: administration, email-alert

We have email alerts setup to notify us internally however I cannot disable them for some reason. I'm not that familiar with SF so I'm wondering if there's some other place than where I'm looking where SF is firing the email event?

All I've tried so far is to disable the workflow by unticking the "Active" checkbox associated with the rule that's using the template in: **Setup > Workflows & Approvals > Workflow Rules**

Are there other ways that I should be aware of?

Many thanks.

Comment: what type of email alerts are you receiving ?

Comment: Email alerts firing on a policy object to notify admins when a policy record is about the expire.